Store diverse JSON structure in the same column of SQL Server database with Entity Framework Core 9
I'm trying to store data in a column of a SQL Server 2019+ database table in a JSON format with Entity Framework Core 9.
This column should store a list of objects of different types, which they have some common properties and other object specific ones.
I'm using interface to define common properties, however as of now Entity Framework Core does not support entities from interfaces.
How can I structure the classes and inheritance to be able to store JSON data of the following structure in a database column.
[
   {
      "common_field_1":"value 1",
      "commonField_2":"value 2"
   },
   {
      "common_field_1":"value 1s",
      "commonField_2":"Value 2 s",
      "custom_field_o2" : "Object type2 custom field"
   },
   {
      "common_field_1":"value 1 th",
      "commonField_2":"Value 2 th",
      "custom_field_o3":[
         "Option 1",
         "Option 2"
      ]
   }
]

I want to profit from EF Core 7+ support for JSON. I don't want to use a backing field which I can handle the storage and retrieval of JSON manually.
What I am currently trying to do is something like this:
public interface ICommonProperties
{
    string common_field_1 { get; set; }
    string commonField_2 { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass : ICommonProperties
{
    public string common_field_1 { get; set; }
    public string commonField_2 { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public string custom_field_o2 { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteClass3 : BaseClass
{
    public List<string> custom_field_o3 { get; set; }
}

public class EntityObject
{
    //... other fields
    public List<WHAT> DynamicJson { get; set; } // ICommonProperties doesn't work here
}


Why are you doing this in the first place? EF is an ORM, not a database driver. It's meant to map Objects to Relational data. If you want to store arbitrary data use ADO.NET directly. You should already know what entities you want to use in your application.  JSON fields aren't tables anyway and don't support inheritance. JSON itself has no way to specify type so which concrete class would you expect to get back?

BTW storing such complex data in JSON is not a good design. Such data can't be indexed or queried efficiently (yet, there's promise for SQL Server 2025). If you wanted arbitrary columns you could already use up to 32K sparse columns per table. Internally, these store data in XML fields

@Panagiotis what I want to do is use some dynamic objects in a relational database. I know that on object oriented database would be a better fit, but that's what I have to use. SQL Server 2016+ has support for JSON querying. One common property defines the object type which I can cast into the appropriate object. What I don't know is how to tell EF this.

object oriented database would be a better fit, not really, you'd still need concrete types. You'd have inheritance but wouldn't be able to deal with "stuff" that isn't define. It's document databases that are schema-less or have a looser schema. In fact, the Cosmos DB provider adds an extra $type to JSON to identify what type to create. JSON.NET does something similar. JSON itself has no types. All the concrete classes could match the third snippet

The real problem here is types and inheritance. You could create a custom JSON converter to map the JSON field to an ICommonProperties or BaseClass type, inspect the contents and create the concrete type. That could break support for JSON query mapping though.

@Panagiotis these are extra data that wont be queried on. They are just for config purposes and they are requested by other field of EntityObject which they are not stored as JSON. If I just make a single object having all the field possibilities of each type that can work but it is not a good OOP practice. That's why I wrote this question.

In that case you can use a JSON converter. In general, ORMs were always a leaky abstraction and not dynamic. You'll always find edge cases and problems - ORMs have been called the Vietnam of Computer Science. Imagine creating a report application that displays results in grids. With ORMs you have to create entities for all results when all you care about are columns and values. EF+LINQ are more flexible but the farther you get from the "normal" cases the more problems you'll find

Even if you treated that JSON as raw data, it's not clear to me how a converter would know which class to deserialize each element as. You would normally have some sort of disciminator property to indicate which class should be used. Otherwise, you're left trying to find a class with a matching set of property names and types, which would be extremely slow and fragile.
